# (SPFieldLookupValue) splistitem of Lookup type throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint list which has some Lookup fields. When I iterate through the items in code, I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This error appears only on lookup fields when they are not filled in with any value. I tried to use `SPFieldLookupValue` to check for null values, but I still get the error.

This is how I check for null values:

```
SPFieldLookupValue value = new SPFieldLookupValue(listItem[columnDisplayName].ToString()); 
if (value.LookupValue != null)
```

Any help guys?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I started with SP2010. This post has [the answer to your problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/03c8022f-bdbd-4a9b-ab76-2c041eddd382).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this exception lies here: `listItem[columnDisplayName].ToString()` because `listItem[columnDisplayName]` have no value and returns null you trying to call `ToString()` on null object so it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception".

If you simply want to check if item field is not null then do like that:

```
if (listItem[columnDisplayName]!=null) 
{
    //here you can access listItem[columnDisplayName] safely
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks a lot for your reply. I have been staring at it all along without realizing that I was not checking the field item for null values. In other codes I used to check field items for null, but this time I was relying on SPFieldLookUpValue thinking that it was the right way to check for nulls. Thanks again for your great help.

Comment: Most likely, passing `null` to `SPFieldLookupValue` is what causes the exception; "Object reference not set..." is a SharePoint exception, not a JavaScript built-in exception. (Calling `null.toString()` would cause a separate "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null".)